keras model weights turning into nan's
I've been trying to train neural network to play blackjack. I'm not using gym instead I used this repo for game base: [https://github.com/ellisandrews/blackjack] and on it started building a network. Whole process of training it is making agent take decisions at every stage, gather data and adjust weights after each turn by calculating gradient by replicating decision process with data gathered during the game and rewards that can only be determined after end of turn.
Firstly I initialize model using this function:
def make_model(layer_sizes: list, input_layer_sizes: list, output_layer_size: int, lr: float):
    he = tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform()
    flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    inputs = [
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=size) for size in input_layer_sizes
    ]
    hidden_layers = [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(size, activation=None, kernel_initializer=he,     kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)) for size in layer_sizes
    ]
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_layer_size, activation='softplus')

    x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([flatten(input) for input in inputs])
    for layer in hidden_layers:
       x = layer(x)
    outputs = output_layer(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='functional')

    model.compile(
       optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr, clipnorm=1.0),
    )

    return model

With these inputs:
self.model = make_model(layer_sizes=[92, 44], input_layer_sizes=[(1, 10), (1, 10), (1, 10), (1, 5)], output_layer_size=22, lr=self.alpha)
In this case first input is odds of drawing each card, second is known dealer hand, third is agent hand and fourth is stage (checking wager, changing wager, playing hand etc.). Output is 22 positive numbers (because there is overall 22 possible actions).
Then game is played and data for episode is gathered and after each turn this function is called:
def update_policy(self):
    # Return if agent didn't get chance to take any actions
    if len(self.episode[0]) == 0:
        return
    episode = list(zip(*self.episode))
    states, actions, rewards = zip(*episode)
    input1, input2, input3, input4 = [], [], [], []

    for state in states:
        input1.append(state[0])
        input2.append(state[1])
        input3.append(state[2])
        input4.append(state[3])

    input1 = np.vstack(input1)
    input2 = np.vstack(input2)
    input3 = np.vstack(input3)
    input4 = np.vstack(input4)

    stacked_states = [input1, input2, input3, input4]
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        action_probs = self.model(stacked_states)
        loss = self.compute_policy_gradient_loss(action_probs, actions, rewards)
    
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
    self.model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_variables))

def compute_policy_gradient_loss(self, action_probs, actions, discounted_rewards):
    action_indices = tf.cast(actions, tf.int32)
    actions_one_hot = tf.one_hot(action_indices, depth=action_probs.shape[-1])
    log_probs = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.log(action_probs) * actions_one_hot, axis=-1)
    loss = -tf.reduce_mean(log_probs * discounted_rewards)
    if np.isnan(loss.numpy()):
        self.model.save(path.join('c:\\Users\\olo32\\Desktop\\dacdsfgd', 'model_.keras'), overwrite=True)
        raise ValueError('Loss is nan') # Raise error if loss becomes nan, usually happens because weights before somehow flip to nan and output is nan's
    return loss

After some training (hard to tell how many episodes, it happens randomly soon after starting training) weights change to nan and because of that output becomes just 22 nan's.
I'm 100% certain no nan's are being passed to model.
I tried using sequential api, adding batch normalization layers, normalizing rewards (I'll post reward function below), clipvalue and clipnorm for gradient, different output layer activasion functions (softmax, sigmoid and even custom sigmoid clipped between 0.01 and 0.99) different kernel initializers, different learning rates, SGD optimizer (then issue still occurred but later than with Adam), I even tried making a simpler model (just playing hand stage) but none of these have worked.
Calculating rewards:
    rewards = []
    # Add first award for first action which is deciding whether to change wager or not, reward is just difference between bankroll after turn and bankroll pre turn
    rewards.append(self.gambler.bankroll - self.init_bankroll)
    # If agent changed wager wager add another same reward
    if self.changed_wager:
        rewards.append(self.gambler.bankroll - self.init_bankroll)

    # Now for each wager get difference and multiply by given bonus/penalty, here also cases where agent refused to get insurance are counted because artificial wagers are created for that
    for wager in self.placed_wagers:
        diff = wager['payout'] - wager['wager']
        match wager['outcome']:
            case 'Insurance Loss':
                reward = diff * self.insurance_loss
            case 'Insurance Won':
                reward = diff * self.insurance_had_blackjack
            case 'Even Money - Dealer Had Blackjack':
                reward = diff * self.even_money_win
            case 'Even Money - Dealer Did Not Have Blackjack':
                reward = diff * self.even_money_loss
            case 'Bust':
                reward = diff * self.bust
            case _:
                reward = diff
        # If wager is not of type 'auto_wager' add reward to list otherwise it must have some hand actions for which rewards must be also given
        if not wager['type'] == 'auto_wager':
            rewards.append(reward)
        else:
            len_actions = len(wager['actions'])
            if len_actions == 1:
                rewards.append(reward)
            else:
                for i in range(len_actions):
                    # If action is 'Hit' and it's not last action in for wager that means it brought agent closer to 21 and was not a bust so it gets reward of 0.25 wager
                    if i != len_actions - 1:
                        if wager['actions'][i] == 'Hit':
                            reward_ = wager['wager'] * 0.25
                            rewards.append(reward_)
                        else:
                            rewards.append(0.0)
                    else:
                        # Finally add reward for whole wager for the last action inside it
                        rewards.append(reward)

Discounting rewards:
def get_discounted_rewards(self, rewards: list, gamma: float) -> list:
    discounted = []
    R = 0.0
    for i, r in enumerate(reversed(rewards)):
        R += r * (gamma**i)
        discounted.insert(0, R)
    return (discounted, R)

discounted_rewards, R = self.get_discounted_rewards(rewards, 0.99)
# Extend rewards list in episode with discounted rewards
self.episode[2].extend(discounted_rewards)


Here's whole class if think it might be helpful (it's like 800 lines): https://pastebin.pl/view/6fdf5961
